# How can I combine similar rows in SAS?

Tags: sas

I have data in SAS like this:

```
Role                      Answer
A                              -
A                         Diabetes
B                             -
B                         Diabetes
B                         Diabetes
B                             -
C                             -
C                             -
```

As you can see, out of role A, only one answered the question, so the response rate would be 50%. Similarly, in role B two people answered the question. The response rate would be 33.33%. For C, it would be 0%.

How can I combine similar rows so that my data would look like this:

```
Role                  Response Rate
A                          1(50%)
B                          2 (33%)
C                          0 (0%)
```

OR

```
                    A          B                 C
Reponse Rate     1(50%)      2(33%)            0(0%)
```

I have tried everything I know about SAS.

Comment: SAS the statistical suite, as opposed to the hard drive format, i presume - in which case, we may need to look up a way to seperate the tags...

Comment: @ Journeyman: thanks! which tag should I use for SAS questions?

Comment: I'm not actually sure - i've asked on meta since this is not a situation that I've seen so far. I'd leave it as is for now.

Comment: I'd recommend asking SAS programming language questions on www.stackoverflow.com rather than this site. Also, why is the response rate 33% for B? You have 2 answers out of 4 rows, so I'd have thought it would be 50%.